# $UTM_n[D]$ is artinian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Why is the upper triangular matrices over a division ring D is artinian?
I tried to find properties of this class of rings. The only thing I found that the jacobson radical of this ring is the strictly upper triangular matrices over D.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: right ideals are also right $D$-subspaces. What can you say about the $D$-dimension of $UTM_n(D)$?

The same argument works on the left side.

Comment: I got it. Thankyou :)